# Expressing Maths Equation in MIPS

Tags: assembly, expression, mips

What is the most efficient way to represent the following expression in MIPS

```
$v0 = $a0 * $a1 / $a3;
```

Comment: That depends; are any of the values in the expression a power of two?

Comment: not consistently, but they might be every so often

Comment: You could avoid the division  if $a0 * $a1 is a power of two or if $a3 is power of two and use a bit-wise shift.  Otherwise, you're stuck with the division.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't depend on that scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preserving operator precedence:

```
mult $t0,$a0,$a1
div $v0,$t0,$a3
```

Assuming of course that register $t0 is not already in use.

Comment: Thanks Erik, I assumed there would be a fancy efficient way with bit shifting or something, is this the most efficient way?

Comment: Well no, it's not the most efficient way but it has the virtue of being correct regardless of the input.  In order to use bit-shifting to replace multiplication and division, one of the operands needs to be a power of two.